# Re-use aggregate result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm searching for a way to re-use the results of an aggregate function applied to a particular column to filter the values from this column.
Running:

```
SELECT * FROM sales_info 
WHERE sales>(SELECT MIN(sales) from sales_info);
```

returns the table in which the minimal sales value is excluded, as expected. However, I can't find a way to keep and re-use this minimal value in further calculations.
When trying:

```
WITH min_sales AS (SELECT MIN(sales) from sales_info)
        SELECT * FROM sales_info 
        WHERE sales> min_sales
```

I'm getting:

> ERROR:  column "min_sales" does not exist
> LINE 3:         WHERE sales> min_sales;

Why am I getting this error? What would be the simplest way to re-use the minimal sales value?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the CTE in the FROM clause of the final query:

```
WITH min_sales AS (
  SELECT MIN(sales) as sales_min
  from sales_info
)
SELECT * 
FROM sales_info 
WHERE sales> (select sales_min from min_sales);
```

Or

```
WITH min_sales AS (
  SELECT MIN(sales) as sales_min
  from sales_info
)
SELECT si.*
FROM sales_info si
  cross join min_sales ms
WHERE si.sales > ms.sales_min;
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, so there's no way to use min_sales as an integer threshold, as I would could do with, for example 'WHERE sales>120', right? I can only re-use it as a column, am I correct?